# How to store an array inside an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

We have two worksheets (Source & Target). We are matching Header Names in both sheets.

The code is working. It is writing the column names inside (myarray) every time. I need it to be flexible to be called from a range instead.

**Replace**

```vb
' Define target headers to search for   
myarray = Array("Customer Name", "Delivery Date", "Agent (#)", "User_ID")
```

**With**

#Attempt 1

```vb
' Define target headers to search for   
myarray = Array(Targetsheet.range("A2:A5").value)
```

#Attempt 2

```vb
Dim Dir as variant
Dir = Targetsheet.range("A2:A5").value
' Define target headers to search for   
myarray = Array(Dir)
```

Where `Targetsheet.range("A2:A5")` values are:
"Customer Name", "Delivery Date", "Agent (#)", "User_ID"

**The issue**

> Error '13' Runtime error

Refers to the function below. I don't know how to debug this function.

**Main Module**

```vb
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
End Function

Sub MatchHeaders()

    ' Declare logic variables
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, TargetSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceSheet = GetWorkbook(Source).Worksheets("Data")
    Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long, Header As Range, FoundHeader As Range, lcol As Long
            
    lastRow = SourceSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lcol = TargetSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ' Loop through all headers in target worksheet
    For Each Header In TargetSheet.Range(TargetSheet.Cells(1, 1), TargetSheet.Cells(1, lcol))
                    
        ' Search for Header Names
        Set FoundHeader = SourceSheet.Rows(1).Find(Header, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    
        ' ## Store result in a string called hdr (it is necessary to declare it in a string to avoid runtime error)
        Dim hdr As String
        hdr = FoundHeader
        
        ' Define target headers to search for
        myarray = Array("Customer Name", "Delivery Date", "Agent (#)", "User_ID")   
            
        ' ## If (target header names are matching - Source/Destination) & (Target Header is found in myarray) then copy from src and paste in dst.
                    
        If Not FoundHeader Is Nothing And IsInArray(hdr, myarray) = True Then
            Debug.Print FoundHeader     
        End If
    
        On Error Resume Next  ' Critical Null (Runtime purposes)
    
    Next Header  ' Loop the above process until done matching all headers
End Sub
```

**Helper Module**

```vb
Public Const Source As String = "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\User_2.xlsb"

Public Function GetWorkbook(ByVal sFullName As String) As Workbook
        
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim wbReturn As Workbook
        
    sFile = Dir(sFullName)
        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbReturn = Workbooks(sFile)
        
    If wbReturn Is Nothing Then
        Set wbReturn = Workbooks.Open(sFullName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    Set GetWorkbook = wbReturn
        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your first attempt:-

```
myArray = Targetsheet.Range("A2:A5").value
```

This will create a 1-based 2-D array of one row and 4 columns. Therefore UBound(myArray) = 1 and UBound(MyArray, 2) = 4. Therefore the value originating from A2 will be myArray(1, 1) and the one from B2 will be myArray(1, 2), where 1 represents the first row of the array.

You can store this array in another array (if that is your question).

```
Dim hisArray As Variant
Redim hisArray(1 to 10)
hisArray(1) = myArray
Debug.Print hisArray(1)(1,2)    'returns the value originating in B2
```

Comment: yes you are correct, but the issue is related to type mismatch error '13' runtime error for this function     Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1
    End Function

Comment: Try `Arr() as Variant` if the variant you are passing contains arrays. I also doubt that `Filter(arr, stringToBeFound))` represents an array whose UBound you can ask.